# Insert null value to date field in access using vba

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

Am trying to insert date from a table to another table using vba in access, But one of the date values from the table is blank. So while inserting the date to new table it shows **Invalid use of null exception** **Run-time  error 94**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figure it out , declare the variable to string. Then check whether value from the table is empty, then assign null to it.Other wise assign the value from the table.

for example

```
   Dim newdate As String
```

Check whether the fetched values is null or not

```
   If IsNull(rst![value]) Then
            newdate = "null"
   Else
           newdate = rst![value]
   End If
```

Answer (score 4):

If writing DAO code to clear a Date field, I found that I had to use "Empty".  Null and "" won't work. So for field dtmDelivery (type Date), I had to use the following. strDelivery is just a string with the date in it.

```
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblSomething", dbOpenDynaset)
If (strDelivery = "") Then                      
    rst!dtmDelivery = Empty    
Else 
    rst!dtmDelivery = strDelivery
End If

rst.Update
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the NZ() function to define a value that should be used instead of NULL. Internally a date is a float value where the number represents the days between 01.01.1900 and the date that should be stored. The part behind the decimal point represents hours/minutes (.25 for example is 6 AM). So you can use the NZ() funtion to replace NULL bei 0 (what would be interpreted as 01.01.1900).

Another solution would be to configure the target table in a way that it allows NULL values. You can do this easily in the design view of the table.

Comment: I have set the required field status to no.Still does not work. And is it possible to leave the field as blank if there is no value to be inserted?

Comment: you have to change the "requiered" property of the field in the table design.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and solved it this way.

```
SQL = "update mytable set mydatefield = '" & txtdate & "'"
```

On the `txtdate` on your form, put a date format to ensure date is either a real date or just blank.